# How to set the flag BUILD_ONLY for multiple modules?

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

I am trying to build only certain modules, e.g. s2, dynamodb, and cognito from the source code.  I use various settings to pass to cmake but none works.

1. -DBUILD_ONLY=s3 -DBUILD_ONLY=dynamodb -DBUILD_ONLY=cognito. (Only the last one gets built.)
2. -DBUILD_ONLY=s3,dynamodb,cognito. (Unrecognized module because the whole string is treaded as module name)
3. -DBUILD_ONLY="s3 dynamodb cognito" (Same error.)

Answer (score 4):

-DBUILD_ONLY="service1;service2;service3"